# How to install matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.2

I installed python3.2 in ubuntu (the default edition is not deleted), and I follow the steps in [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#how-to-install)

However when i use

```
python3.2 setup.py install
```

I got:

```
 "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1",
"src/ft2font.cpp:2224:29: error: ‘Int’ is not a member of ‘Py’"
```

And when I use 
`sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` 
 I can use matplot in python2.x, while I still can not use it with python3.2
How can I install matplot in python3.2 ?

Comment: As of version 1.2 ( released in November 2012 ) matplotlib does now support Python 3.2, but prior to this you would have needed to build from github as answered below.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Matplotlib supports python 3.x as of version 1.2, released in January, 2013.

To install it, have a look at the [installation instructions](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html). In general, call `pip install matplotlib` or use your preferred mechanism (`conda`, `homebrew`, windows installer, system package manager, etc). In some cases you may need to install additional non-python dependencies (`libpng` and `freetype`) through your system's package manager.

The answer below is left for historical reasons and as an example of installing the development version from github.

---

The current release of matplotlib doesn't support python3.

There's a github branch for python3 support for a couple of years now, but it hasn't been stable on anything other than linux until fairly recently.  I believe that branch was recently merged back into the main branch.

If you want to use matplotlib on python3, you'll need to build from the current tip https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

To build it, do something similar to the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib
cd matplotlib
python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

If you don't have git installed, then you can just download a tarball of the current git tip instead: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tarball/master

You'll need to have numpy installed for python3.  (Installing it for python2 doesn't install it for python3.)

In most cases, that's all you'll need to do.  For a default install, the only non-included python library is numpy.  The other dependencies (e.g. `libpng`, `freetype`) are system libraries and if you can build matplotlib for python2, you already have them.

If you want a non-default install (e.g. if you want any of the non-default backends), then you'll need to copy the `setup.cfg.default` template to `setup.cfg` and edit it to match what you want.  You'll probably only need to do this if you're planning to embed matplotlib in a gtk or qt application that you're writing, in which case you'll want the `gtkagg` or `qtagg` backends instead of just the default `tkagg` backend.

Comment: How to build it? Can I just type 'python3.2 setup.py install'

Comment: Thank you. It really work. After that, I got "module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'", while it can be solved by [link](http://paltman.com/2007/11/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/)

Comment: This is outdated, right? Ubuntu has a python3-matplotlib in latest releases

Comment: @endolith - Yes, absolutely! Matplotlib has supported python3 since version 1.2. At the time of the original question, though, it didn't yet.  (I should update the answer, though. Thanks for the reminder!)

Comment: I had to install using pip3 instead of regular pip because all of my other libraries were installed using pip3

Answer (score 23):

just to bump @endolith's comment up to answer level, from at least uBuntu 14-04 linux onwards, matplotlib support for python3 is built-in with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

should install matplotlib for python3 with the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

This should get all the dependencies required for installing matplotlib

Comment: It just install the libraries need to install matplotlib.
After that you need to install with pip or with python3 setup.py install...

Answer (score 3):

Try Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages if you are running windows.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps by  **Joe Kington**  on Ubuntu 14.04. Though those steps got me get started ran into few issues. I had to do the following additional steps. Hope it helps someone else who has similar problems.

1. Install freetype package using

   ```
       sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
   ```
2. I had to install g++ because of this error:  
   **error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory**

   ```
       sudo apt-get install g++
   ```
3. Then I have to install python3.4-dev because of :  **fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory**

   ```
       sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev
   ```

Now run the steps from **Joe Kington**. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's simplicity itself.

`sudo pip install matplotlib` will do the trick.