# Gnuplot for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, gnuplot

I have a problem with python 3.2.3 and Gnuplot. I have installed gnuplot-4.6.1, it's going well with defaults demo, but an error occurs when i want to import the module in the python environnement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Gnuplot
```

I don't know what's wrong with python3

ps: before gnuplot-4.6.1, i had gnuplot1.8 and i used it for plot

Answer (score 3):

I assume you need to install `Gnuplot-py` for your version of python.

Since `Gnuplot-py` doesn't seem to be actively supported much these days, I'm not sure if it will work on python3.x or not (You'll need to try it and see).

Another option is `pyGnuplot` which I develop and I aim to keep it py3k compatable (although I don't test that very often).  It is not a drop in replacement for Gnuplot-py however, so you'd need to change your code in order to use it.

Finally, (probably the most popular option these days) is `matplotlib`.  My impression is that it gives an interface which is designed to make people familiar with MATLAB a little more comfortable and it is pretty powerful.  I know a lot of people are very happy with it.

Comment: i am going to try `matplotlib` and i will give you a feedback. Previously, when i said Gnulot-4.6.1 or the other version, i wanted to say Gnuplo.py version 4.6.1 [http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/]

Comment: `matplotlib` is not supported by python3, but it exist a solution that builds from github[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2], i'm trying

Comment: This port of gnuplot-py to python 3 appears to work: https://github.com/PavelTrutman/gnuplot.py-py3k