# Error message installing "Gnuplot-py" with "python setup.py install" command in Mac OS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, gnuplot

I'm trying to install the "Gnuplot-py" package on my Mac using this command "python setup.py install" within the gnuplot-py-1.8 directory but I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/Users/sebydc77/Downloads/gnuplot-py-1.8/PlotItems.py", line
>   20, in 
>       from cStringIO import StringIO ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "setup.py", line 15, in 
>       from **init** import **version**   File "/Users/sebydc77/Downloads/gnuplot-py-1.8/**init**.py", line 166, in
>   
>       from PlotItems import PlotItem, Func, File, Data, GridData   File "/Users/sebydc77/Downloads/gnuplot-py-1.8/PlotItems.py", line 22, in
>   
>       from StringIO import StringIO ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'

I spent at least 3 hours trying to solve this problem. I also tried different alternatives such as "pip install Gnuplot-py", "pip install download link..." etc...

(NOTE: I already have gnuplot installed on my machine)

Comment: looks like you are using Python 3 (judging by the missing `StringIO` module)? Gnuplot-py works only with Python 2.X I believe - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12840346/5351549

Comment: You were partly right. I created a new environment with miniconda for the 2.7 version. At first I got an error, but these commands solved it: 1) brew install Caskroom/cask/aquaterm  2) brew reinstall gnuplot --with-aquaterm
THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the module doesn't work with Python 3.

But it isn't all that hard to write a *custom plot function* using `gnuplot` in Python. Below is an example that I wrote to make a graph of the infusion of carbon fiber laminates with epoxy resin. During the infusion, the pail of resin is placed on a scale, so I can write down the remaining weight every couple of minutes.

The main input for the `plot` function is a `numpy` array where I have recorded the time and amount of resin still in the bucket. This amount goes down over time, so I use this data to calculate the total amount of injected resin at every point and the speed with which the resin flows. That's where `numpy` comes in handy!

Basically this function creates a list of lines containing gnuplot commands and inline data, which is then joined into a single string and fed to `gnuplot` running as a `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np


def plot(rawdata, filename, maxy=None, labels=False, n=2):
    """Plot injection data with gnuplot.

    Arguments:
        data: numpy array of shape (N,2)
            (Time, weight) pairs as written down during the injection. The time
            in minutes increases and the weight in grams decreases.
        filename: string
            Name to write the output figure to.
        maxy: Maximum y coordinate for the left axis (injected weight).
            The right axis (injection speed) is 1/10th of the left axis.
            When set to None, automatic scaling is used.
        labels: Label every n-th data point when true.
        n: Print every n-th value as a label.
    """
    gtype = 'lines'
    if labels:
        gtype = 'linespoints'
    delta = rawdata[1:] - rawdata[:-1]
    totals = np.array([[0, 0]] + [[dt, -dm] for dt, dm in delta])
    som = np.cumsum(totals, axis=0)
    print('harshoeveelheid "{}": {} g'.format(filename, som[-1, 1]))
    if maxy is None:
        maxy = round(som[-1, 1], -2)
    dm = np.array([[0]] + [[-dm/dt] for dt, dm in delta])
    newdata = np.hstack((som, dm))
    newdata[0, 2] = newdata[1, 2]
    l1 = 'set label "{:.0f} g" at {},{} center offset 0,0.5'
    l2 = 'set label "{:.0f} g/min" at {},second {} center offset 0,0.5'
    p1 = 'plot "-" with {gt} ls 1 title "harshoeveelheid", ' \
        '"-" with {gt} axes x1y2 ls 2 title "injectiesnelheid"'
    lp1 = ', "-" using 1:2:2 with labels right offset character 0.4,0.7' \
        'font "Alegreya, 8" tc ls 1 notitle'
    lp2 = ', "-" using 1:2:2 axis x1y2 with labels left offset character ' \
        '0.5,0.7 font "Alegreya, 8" tc ls 2 notitle'
    text = ['set terminal pdfcairo enhanced color dashed font "Alegreya, 11" '
            'rounded size 12.8 cm, 7.0 cm',
            'set xlabel "tijd [min]"',
            'set ylabel "harshoeveelheid [g]"',
            'set y2label "injectiesnelheid [g/min]"',
            'set y2tics',
            'set yrange [0:{:.0f}]'.format(maxy),
            'set y2range [0:{:.0f}]'.format(maxy/10),
            'set key left bottom',
            'set grid']
    if not labels:
        text.append(l1.format(newdata[-1, 1], newdata[-1, 0], newdata[-1, 1]))
        text.append(l2.format(newdata[-1, 2], newdata[-1, 0], newdata[-1, 2]))
    text.append('set output "{}"'.format(filename + '.pdf'))
    text.append(p1.format(gt=gtype))
    if labels:
        text[-1] += lp1 + lp2
    data1 = ['{:2.0f} {:4.0f}'.format(a, b) for a, b, _ in newdata]
    data2 = ['{:2.0f} {:4.0f}'.format(a, b) for a, _, b in newdata]
    text += data1
    text.append('e')
    text += data2
    text.append('e')
    if labels:
        data1 = ['{:2.0f} {:4.0f}'.format(a, b) for a, b, _ in newdata[n-1::n]]
        data2 = ['{:2.0f} {:4.0f}'.format(a, b) for a, _, b in newdata[n-1::n]]
        text += data1
        text.append('e')
        text += data2
        text.append('e')
    p = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    _, _ = p.communicate(input='\n'.join(text).encode('utf-8'))
```

The output looks something like this:
[image: example infusion picture]

Note that the style of the graph is determined by the settings in my `gnuplotrc` file.