# error with gcc when install matplotlib with python3

Tags: gcc, python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install `matplotlib` with python3 as mentionned in [How to install matplotlib with Python3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2). An error occurs: **command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1** when i do

```
python3 setup.py build

 basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']
 ============================================================================
 BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
        matplotlib: 1.3.x
            python: 3.2.3 (default, Sep 10 2012, 18:14:40)  [GCC 4.6.3]
          platform: linux2

 REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
             numpy: 1.6.1
         freetype2: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
                    * WARNING: Could not find 'freetype2' headers in any
                    * of '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include',
                    * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '.',
                    * '/usr/local/include/freetype2',
                    * '/usr/include/freetype2',
                    * '/usr/local/include/freetype2',
                    * '/usr/include/freetype2', './freetype2'.

OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
            libpng: found, but unknown version (no pkg-config)
                    * Could not find 'libpng' headers in any of
                    * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include',
                    * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '.'
           Tkinter: no
                    * Using default library and include directories for
                    * Tcl and Tk because a Tk window failed to open.
                    * You may need to define DISPLAY for Tk to work so
                    * that setup can determine where your libraries are
                    * located. Tkinter present, but header files are not
                    * found. You may need to install development
                    * packages.
              Gtk+: no
                    * Building for Gtk+ requires pygtk; you must be able
                     * to "import gtk" in your build/install environment
    Mac OS X native: no
                Qt: no
               Qt4: no
            PySide: no
             Cairo: no

OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
          dateutil: matplotlib will provide
              pytz: matplotlib will provide
               six: matplotlib will provide
adding pytz

OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
            dvipng: 1.14
       ghostscript: 9.05
             latex: 3.1415926
           pdftops: 0.18.4

[Edit setup.cfg to suppress the above messages]
============================================================================
pymods ['pylab', 'six']
packages ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor',   'matplotlib.projections', 'matplotlib.testing', 'matplotlib.testing.jpl_units', 'matplotlib.tests', 'mpl_toolkits', 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid', 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1', 'mpl_toolkits.axisartist', 'matplotlib.sphinxext', 'matplotlib.tri', 'matplotlib.delaunay', 'pytz', 'dateutil', 'dateutil.zoneinfo']
running install
running build
running build_py
copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64- 3.2/matplotlib/mpl-data

running build_ext
building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer- size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -DPYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I./freetype2 - I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/src/ft2font.o
In file included from ./CXX/Extensions.hxx:37:0,
             from src/ft2font.h:6,
             from src/ft2font.cpp:3:
./CXX/WrapPython.h:58:20: erreur fatale: Python.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried the answer in the post [error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet) but obtained the same error.
How can i do?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the *Python 3* development files (headers and static libraries). For example in Ubuntu, you can install the relevant package with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

You'll also need the `freetype2` development package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Comment: I did it, but i have now another error: `src/ft2font.h:16:22: fatal error: ft2build.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type`

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution after installing many libraries...
I finally build all the dependancies with:

```
 sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

and after:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Thanks for your help Pedro

Comment: The important part is to use `python3` instead of `python`, if python3 is not the default version.