# Cannot import matplotlib in Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, freetype

I want to install matplotlib on windows. To do this I tried those lines,

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib
cd matplotlib
py setup.py build
py setup.py install
```

which I found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2)

But I think the installation does not succesfully occured. This is result of `py setup.py install`:

[image]

So still following imports does not work;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

An error says Unresolved import. So I am supposing this is because freetype and png did not installed.

Now I found freetype.dll and installed it but where should I put that file?

Any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Matplotlib has some dependencies that need to be installed in order for the library to function fully. [Quoting](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-from-source):

> Once you have satisfied the requirements detailed below (mainly
>   python, numpy, libpng and freetype), you can build matplotlib:
>
> cd matplotlib python setup.py build python setup.py install

To be sure of the correct procedure check the [build instructions](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements). If this process seems somewhat complex (it sometimes is) you can consider Python distributions such as:

1) [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/)

2) [Python XY](https://python-xy.github.io/)

3) [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

, that already bring several libraries by default and making it a lot easier to work with Python (and extensions).

Comment: Thank you so much I installed WinPython and it is great!