# fix matplotlib 'not installed as framework' error w/out changing .matplotlib config in $HOME

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, tensorflow, virtualenv

**context**

- machine: 64-bit Mac
- OS: macOS 10.10.5

**error msg**

following course [`Jerry Kurata 'Tensorflow: Getting Started'`] ran the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

num_house = 160
np.random.seed(42)
house_size = np.random.randint(low=1000, high=3500, size=num_house)

np.random.seed(42)
house_price = house_size * 100.0 + np.random.randint(low=20000, high=70000, size=num_house)

plt.plot(house_size, house_price, "bx")
plt.xlabel("price")
plt.ylabel("size")
plt.show
```

received this error

`**RuntimeError**: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework.`

**attempt to fix**

- have consulted this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789908/6813490] but concerned to change anything related to global matplotlib settings in a way that would affect other projects outside this virtual environment

Comment: my issue here is more specific: solve the error **without changing .matplotlib config in $HOME**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

see the above answer [Installation Issue with matplotlib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python/21789908#21789908) and reference one of the comments:

> Some users may not want to change the backend for all of their
>   scripts. This page --
>   matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend -- tells another
>   way: include the statement import matplotlib as mpl then
>   mpl.use('TkAgg') right after that, then do the import for pyplot.

and set the matplotlib backend in the imports, like so

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math

## SET BACKEND
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

num_house = 160
np.random.seed(42)
house_size = np.random.randint(low=1000, high=3500, size=num_house)

np.random.seed(42)
house_price = house_size * 100.0 + np.random.randint(low=20000, high=70000, size=num_house)

plt.plot(house_size, house_price, "bx")
plt.xlabel("price")
plt.ylabel("size")
plt.show
```

in this way, you won't need to touch the matplotlib in $HOME

Comment: I installed matplotlib for Python3 following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2 and I had the same error.

I just added the 2 lines

`
## SET BACKEND
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
`

and it solved the issue. thank you!